# Chrome and SSL: problem with login and cart

Tags: cart, login, cookie, ssl, chrome-browser

I have a domain with SSL and ***some problems ONLY with Google Chrome*** (`v. 39.0.2171.95 m`).

When a user ***tries to login*** with SSL (`https: //www.mydomain.com/customer/account/login/`), ***he returns to the login page*** (the same) and it doesn't go on... Come back always!

If a user ***tries to log in within the cart*** (because he is registered) after he added an item, it works fine (login) and all his items are in the cart (`http:// www.mydomain.com/checkout/cart/`). BUT when ***he clicks on `Continue to checkout`*** button, he ***returns on the cart page with his items*** (the same: `http: //www.mydomain.com/checkout/cart/`); if he ***clicks the 2th time*** on  `Continue to checkout` button, the ***cart becomes empty***!!!

I have no problem with the Admin login and SSL (https:// www.mydomain.com/admin): it works fine.

If I change the base URL SECURE from `https` to `http`, it works!
All that only with Chrome..

This is my configuration on Magento:

- Magento: `v. 1.9.1.0`.
- Theme: Milano themeforest.net
- One page checkout
- Base URL unsecure: http: //www.mydomain.com
- Base URL secure: https: //www.mydomain.com
- use secure urls in frontend: yes
- use secure urls in admin: yes
- cookie filetime: 864001
- cookie path: //
- cookie domain: //
- Use HTTP ony: no
- Cookie Restriction mod: no
- redirect to CMS-page if cookies are disabled: no

I tried also to remove cookie params with this code

```
session_set_cookie_params(
$this->getCookie()->getLifetime(),
$this->getCookie()->getPath()
$this->getCookie()->getDomain(),
$this->getCookie()->isSecure(),
$this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
);
```

or this similar code:

```
session_set_cookie_params(
$this->getCookie()->getLifetime(),
$this->getCookie()->getPath()
/*
$this->getCookie()->getDomain(),
$this->getCookie()->isSecure(),
$this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
*/ 
);
```

but it doesn't work :(

Comment: how you resolved the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually have cookie path and domain set to `//` two forward slashes?

If that is the case Magento won't even be able to set cookies. Try saving config with both values empty and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, it should be a cookies issue if you go to

> System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management

Make sure that both Cookie Path and Cookie Domain are blank then save.

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to solve this too! My apologies for not having seen this question before as I created one a week ago with the same issue [Chrome and SSL: problem with login and cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50213/chrome-and-ssl-problem-with-login-and-cart)

I've just posted my answer there. I'll copy it here in case it helps someone:

> After trying with the usual suspects, I realized this may be because
>   I'm using localhost. As it turns out, Chrome even has some reported
>   bugs about SSL and localhost.
>
> Strangely enough, changing URLs to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost made
>   Chrome to accept cookies for sessions
>
> Not sure why but at least now I know there won't be issues when going
>   into production with a proper certificate