# Magento 1.8 Admin Login Issue

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, admin-login

Magento 1.8 Admin Login Issue  . Unable to login admin for first time. again i try login admin for second time it is working fine.

I tried the below solution but No Luck

```
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50213/chrome-and-ssl-problem-with-login-and-cart
https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/651-unable-to-login-into-the-magento-backend
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491819/magento-admin-login-not-working-in-chrome-but-works-fine-for-firefox
```

Comment: Check : http://www.gurutechnolabs.com/cant-login-into-admin-panel-of-magento-solved/

Comment: Nikunj already tried not working