# Admin Login issue in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.8, admin-login

**Unable to login admin for first time. again i try login admin for second time it is working fine.**

I am using the Chrome Browser below is my configuration of admin

```
http://screencast.com/t/dmaTakZntQ
```

I tried the below but not working

```
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/50213/chrome-and-ssl-problem-with-login-and-cart
https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/651-unable-to-login-into-the-magento-backend
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491819/magento-admin-login-not-working-in-chrome-but-works-fine-for-firefox
```

Comment: Hi, please update your question with some more information: What browser do you use? What does your Session configuration in Magento look like? Otherwise this question is too broad to expect a good answer that helps you.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl : i updated my question please check now